# How to create multiple empty elements inline with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best way to create multiple empty elements inline using React within render in a declarative fashion?

For example, say I wanted 8 empty divs, the following was my first attempt although it doesn't work, is there a better way?

```
render() {
    return (
        <section>
            {
                new Array(8).map(()=> <div />)
            }
        </section>
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it really create 8 divs?

Comment: `Array(8).fill(<div />)`

Comment: This is not really a React issue, -> `Array(8).map(f => 10)`,  do you think this returns an array with 8 elements with the value 10?,.  Unfortunately not, map doesn't iterate empty array elements,.  but like @hindmost pointed out `Array(8).fill(10)`, this would.

Comment: I didn't realise map doesn't iterate empty elements, fill does yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a small helper for it:

```
  const times = (length, fn) => Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => fn(i));
```

To be used as:

```
 times(8, i => <div key={i} />)
```

Comment: This is probably the way I would normally go about it, just wondering if there was a more concise inline method. Is there any advantage to this over using Mike's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55846879/1528308 ?

Comment: @alex it's shorter, more readable (imo) and only iterates once (but that doesnt matter for such small arrays). Filling the array just to be able to iterate it with `.map` makes just little sense to me.

Comment: It does seem a little awkward I agree, your divs are missing keys though.

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to fill the array first:

```js
export default class Example extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            {Array(8).fill(null).map((item, index) => (
                <div key={index}/>
            )}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need the `.fill(null)`, just `fill()` will work, this is because map doesn't iterate empty, but it does iterate undefined..

Comment: TS expects at least one argument for fill, seems like value isn't optional: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Syntax

Comment: Yes, I'd say TS definition is slightly wrong there. A none passed argument in JS is undefined, and undefined is a totally valid value for `fill`..

Answer (score 1):

As seen the simplest option is just `Array(8).fill().map(<div />)`

But one issue with the above is your creating an array to make another array.  It's not a massive issue, but if you like modern JS, a nice solution is iterators.  And of course iterators can be used for other things, not just arrays.

Below is an example.

```js
function *range(r, map) {
  for (let l = 0; l < r; l += 1) yield(map ? map(l) : l);
}

const a1 = Array.from(range(3));
const a2 = Array.from(range(3, m => 2 + m * 2));

console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);

//and of course not just arrays
for (const value of range(3)) console.log(value);
```